# Angular JS spawn ng-switch with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) says

> the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are
>   interpreted as literal string values to match against.

But what if I wanna spawn all the markup blocks (say, some divs with nested content) I may need with `ng-repeat`, fill it with specific for each of them content and set `ng-switch-when` of each of them to value of some variable, say, some `id` field of the object that depicts certain markup block. AFAIK things like `ng-switch-when="{{data.id}}"` won't work. How can I reach the goal? Is it possible at all with `ng-switch` or, maybe, there's no such way and I have to use `ng-if` or something?

As it was asked in the comment I'll try to illustrate what I mean. The thing I'm talking about should look like something like this:

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch on="selectedItem">
        <p ng-switch-when="{{item.id}}">{{item.content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("appCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{id:0, content:"foo"}, {id:1, content:"bar"}];
    // selectedItem should actually be assigned by some user control like radio button but
    // let's simplify and set it manually
    $scope.selectedItem = 0;
}]);
```

Comment: Provide a better example of logic you want to perform even if it is dones as switch that won't work. Perhaps a custom directive would help also. Hard to tell exactly what you want to accomplish

Comment: ng-switch-when="{{data.id}}" should work -- this isn't an expression, it gets interpreted when AngularJS compiles the HTML and replaced with the value. An expression would be ng-switch-when="data.id == 1"

Comment: The way the question is worded now, It feels more like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) than anything.  You are asking about an implementation detail, but not one that makes sense.  in your simplistic example, a filter on the `ng-repeat` would be more appropriate.  I think it may be better if you can show what you are *actually* trying to accomplish, rather than one possible solution that has a better alternative.

Comment: @Claies the point is that i'm studying and wanna know exactly if I can do such thing with ng-switch. The point is not to elaborate some practical solution but to reach understanding of this directive

Comment: @yxfxmx that may be true, but really this isn't the right use for that directive;  in your example, you have taken functionality that is already available in the `ng-repeat` (filtering) and offloaded it to something else.  There really isn't any reason for the people designing `ng-switch` to design, test, and troubleshoot if the directive is capable of doing this task when it's already native to the surrounding process.

Comment: @yxfxmx also, you didn't word it as if you were trying to learn the ins and outs of `ng-switch`, you expressly stated "How can I reach the goal?" and asked for alternatives.  In the contrived example, using `filter` is the most appropriate, but again, there may be another more appropriate solution with real data instead.